# Orion Context broker - query

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In version 0.23 of Orion context broker.

Can I query the context for entities with a certain value on an attribute? How?

Can I query for entities generated at a certain time range? How?

For geolocation Filter. Is there any limit to the polygon vertices besides request size of 1MG?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding attribute value filters, have a look to [this other Q&A post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958690/filter-by-attribute-value-in-orion-context-broker-0-23-0).

Regarding querying for entities generated at a certain time range, we are planning to include that as the `dateModified` pseudo-attribute ("pseudo" in the sense that is not an attribute to be managed by the NGSI client, but by Orion itself), so you could do a query like this one to get all the entities modified from January 1st, 2015 to January 12th, 2015:

```
GET /v2/entities?q=dateModified==2015-01-01..2015-01-12
```

That functionality is not yet implemented, but as workaround your application could manage an attribute with the same semantics. Eg. you could use an entity attribute named `myDate` storing the date as a timestamp and do the same query in the following way:

```
GET /v2/entities?q=myDate==1420070400..1421020800
```

*Note:* 2015-01-01 equals to 1420070400 and 2015-01-12 equals to 1421020800, the following page may help: http://www.timestampgenerator.com

Regarding the limits of the polygon areas in geo-queries, we haven't found a limit so far. However, if you test with a large number and find a limit, please tell us about it.